# Specific loading order on document elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see on this [LIVE DEMO](http://germanalvarez.net/larmon), a loading process bar is shown by using the plugin [PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/), placed right after a png image with a logo, making a fullfilment effect. After the background content is fully loaded, the front image with the loader and the black div that hides all content both dissapear, showing website's content and executing some animations on it.

Due to the fact that no loading order has been given to any of these elements, when executing the website everything is loaded at the same time: the PACE loader, its front png image, and the content hidden after the black background.

As a result, most of the times when the website is executed for the first time, PACE loads first than it's front image, breaking the effect and the aim of the composition.

I need to make it **load first the front png image**, and then start loading all the background content while PACE is executed and shows how the loading process is being completed.

CODE:______________________

HTML:

```
   <body>
//HERE GOES ALL CONTENT THAT LOADS ON THE BACKGROUND
      <div class="velo"></div>
      <div class="velo2"></div>
      <div class="logoLback"></div>
      <div class="logoL"></div> // '.logoL' MUST BE LOADED FIRST OF ALL, THIS IS THE PNG FRONT IMAGE IN FRONT OF THE LOADING BAR
```

JQUERY:

```
Pace.on("done", function(){
$height = $(window).height(); 

setTimeout(function(){     

   $('.pace-progress').animate({'opacity': 0},500); //HIDES AFETER PACE COMPLETES
   $('.logoLback').animate({'opacity': 0},0); //HIDES AFETER PACE COMPLETES

   setTimeout(function(){ 

      $('.logoL,.logoLback,.velo,.velo2').animate({'opacity': 0},1000); //HIDES AFETER PACE COMPLETES

      setTimeout(function(){
         $('.textc').animate({'width': 148,queue: false}, 1200);
         $('.pattern').animate({height: $height,queue: false}, 500);
      },1000);
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.textc,.menu').animate({'height': 363,queue: false}, 1200);
     },2200);
   },500);
},500);
});
```

Comment: please add the relevant code to your question - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have added and comented code

Comment: The elements load in the order they are present in the code. Ones on the top load first. Ones at bottom load last.

Comment: Thank you Maxz, so simple... I'll move related elements to the top and alter their appereance order by z-index. If you want post this as an answer i'll tick in case of success

Comment: Solved. If you want to post the answer i'll tick, in other case Ill answer and close thhe question. Very grateful.